# With non-graphical maps in Leaflet, zoomDelta doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, leaflet

I want to subdivde the number of scrolling wheels it takes to reach max zoom.. but zoomDelta not working. No matter what zoomDelta value is, it zooms by 1 always.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Custom Zoom Control</title>
    <!-- Include Leaflet CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.4/dist/leaflet.css" />
    <!-- Include Leaflet JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.4/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Create a div element with ID 'map' to contain the map -->
    <div id="map" style="width: 600px; height: 400px;"></div>

    <script>
        // Initialize the map with a center, zoom level, and other options
        var map = L.map('map', {
            center: [500, 500], // Initial center latitude and longitude
            zoom: 1, // Initial zoom level
            minZoom: 1, // Minimum zoom level
            maxZoom: 3, // Maximum zoom level
            crs: L.CRS.Simple // Use Simple CRS for image overlay
        });

        // Define bounds for the image overlay
        var bounds = [[0,0], [1000,1000]];

        // Add an image overlay using your image
        var image = L.imageOverlay('Texture/test map.png', bounds).addTo(map);

        // Remove the default zoom control
        map.zoomControl.remove();

        // Add event listener for zoomstart event
        map.on('zoom', function(event) {
            console.log('Current Zoom Level: ' + map.getZoom());
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Console log:

Current Zoom Level: 2 Text6.html:37
Current Zoom Level: 3 Text6.html:37
Current Zoom Level: 2 Text6.html:37
Current Zoom Level: 1 Text6.html:37